# Is there a mode in which protocol buffers can be used without linking against libprotobuf?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'd like to be able to use protocol buffers in a dynamic C++ module that is loaded by a user, but not require that user to also have libprotobuf installed.

Currently I'm looking at moving to flatbuffers which offers this type of mode through a header-only solution.

Does such an approach exist for protocol buffers?

Comment: Isn't it possible to link libprotobuf statically?

Comment: I've not had any luck with this approach, but perhaps I'll revisit it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to statically link in the protocol buffer library into your .dll